# When using JUnit's @Parameterized, can I skip few test data due to bug?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, junit, parameterized-unit-test

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized::class)
class A(private val a: aa,
        private val b: bb,
        private val c: cc,
        private val d: dd
) : UIAutomatorTestCase() { 

@Test
    fun testMethodA() {
       
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Parameterized.Parameters
        fun Arguments() = arrayOf(
            arrayOf(x,xa,xb,xc),
            arrayOf(y,ya,yb,yc),  // want to skip this one 
            arrayOf(z,za,zb,zc))
```

i have many more data as arguments which i run for espresso tests as parameterized tests. But
because of bug i want to skip 2nd data running the tests , how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JUnit's [Assume feature](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assume.html) for conditionally skipping tests. But for that you need to identify the data set that you want to skip in `testMethodA`